# Android - 4.0 is out, which version to use?

Tags: android

I'm just starting to learn Android development and writing my first app. I started with V2.2 but up until now mostly wrote generic Java code. Now that I started to write Android specific code I saw that a new version was out. 
After installing it, eclipse IDE lets me choose between v2.1 and v4.0. non of the others are available.

So should I jump to 4.0 or stay with 2.1 to have the app compatible with a greater number of older handhelds? I'm not planning on using any new technology / functionality that 4.0 might be offering.

Comment: You should use 2.1/2.2 if you want to actually distribute your app. Take a look at http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html.

Comment: Thanks. Any technological reason to go with 2.2 over 2.1?

Comment: It depends on the tech requirements of your app!

Comment: Just simple 2d graphics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each new version of the API introduces new functionalities but remains compatible with earlier versions.
To keep your app compatible with the greater number of devices, use the lowest [API level](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html) which it requires.

Answer (score 1):

The app written in older version can be compatible with higher version but vice versa is not possible. so use older one.

Answer (score 1):

Another point that can help make a decision is API level vs. number of devices running it.

The [`android device dashboard`](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html) offers a permanent survey of android devices version based on Android Market access (14 days). It looks like this:

[image: Android Device DashBoard]